# wkhtmltopdf pdf temp file isn't being deleted, simple c++ query

Tags: html, c++, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the newest binary (wkhtmltox-0.12.1.1_msvc2013-win64.exe) on Windows 2012 server with params: "--zoom 1.4 --margin-top 0 --disable-javascript --margin-right 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --quiet - -"

I am sending HTML file through stdin and getting PDF directly with stdout. The temp HTML files are removed, but PDFs remain in C:\Windows\Temp

This presents a problem when using it in production as disk slowly fills up (or quite rapidly in our case).

Ideally the temp PDF files wouldn't be necessary as they are associated with a performance penalty when outputting to STDOUT. It seems on Windows that it isn't an option, because QPrinter in QT4.8 will only accept file names and Windows doesn't use file system paths as streams (i.e. /dev/stdout).

from pdfconverter.cc:335

```
if (settings.out == "-") {
#ifndef Q_OS_WIN32
     if (QFile::exists("/dev/stdout"))
         lout = "/dev/stdout";
     else
#endif
         lout = tempOut.create(".pdf");
}
```

QPdfWriter in qt5+ does, however, seem to have support for output to a QByteArray. I assume that will be used when the qt5 branch is done. Is there anything that can be done in the interim to avoid these temp files on win32?

Comment: You seem to have found the bug (pdfconverter.cc:335), so why don't you just fix it?

Comment: Because I can't download the library right now and seeing as how it seems pretty major, I thought someone would've had a fix already..

Comment: You can't clone the repo? Why not? Just type "git clone https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.git"

Comment: It's linked statically to the qt stack, which you need to compile. After going home and downloading qt, and making the c++ change, I now receive a compilation error of "error2 the system cannot find the file specified .../deplibs

Comment: No offence chaps but telling me to fix it or how to clone a repo is not what I was looking for...